# How do I record roll over of IRA and CMA into the purchase of service credits on my federal income tax?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ira, retirement

I work for the a county government with its own retirement system.  I served about 10 years in the military.  A couple of years ago I found out my dad had put money in an IRA and a UTMA CMA for me.  I cashed those out to purchase my 10 years of military service into my current retirement system.  My understanding is that I could cash out an IRA and use it to make the service credit purchase with out paying taxes on the IRA disbursement if done within 60 days.

So how do I reconcile this when filing my federal income tax?

Thanks to anyone who can help.